# Image save in dynamic create folder in gallery

Tags: ipad

Here i m trying to save image in gallery. i done this but now i want to save captured image in date wise folder in gallery.

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingSlate.bounds.size, drawingSlate.opaque, 0.0);
[drawingSlate.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

 }
```

here the image is save in photos, but i want to save with proper name and datewise folder.

Thanks